# Can graphons be useful outside of extremal graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory

I was recently introduced to the notion of a **Graphon** ([[Quick introduction]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.00718.pdf), [[Original definition]](http://web.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/bookxx/hombook-almost.final.pdf)) and I have been fascinated by the idea behind them and the way they combine fields such as graph theory, measure theory, probability, and functional analysis. Skimming through the limited literature around them, I have been wondering whether these structures could be useful outside of extremal graph theory, (edit:) besides property testing?

Comment: Chapter 15 of the book by Lovasz has algorithmic applications, mainly to property testing.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said, besides the ones mentioned in the Lovasz's book.